# number_format() with 100% width

Tags: php

I am using php function number_format() to make my variable looking not so long when displayed on the frontend. (ex: 12,3456789). I need something more compact so I just used:

```
$grade_1_parts = number_format($grade_1_parts, 2, '.', ',');
```

I use 9 grade_parts variables like percentage number and when the number_format function compresses all of them it makes the number a little bit more than 100% (something like 100,4) and this is a problem for me because it can't be displayed on one row. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: if it's greater than 100 then set it to 100. if not leave it as his.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably due to rounding errors. The documentation isn't clear, but the very first comment says that `number_format` also rounds the number: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#88424

So, you're probably adding up slightly bigger numbers than the original values. If you know for certain the result should always be 100%, then just use 100% hardcoded in your row. If you really want to sum all the values, use the original value *before* you use `number_format`. Beware though, calculations with PHP's floating point number can still give unexpected results: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: I used :
$grade_2_parts = number_format(floor($grade_2_parts*pow(10,2))/pow(10,2),2);
and it works. Thanks a lot!